# Is containerizing only the application server bad practice?

Tags: kubernetes, containers

## Context

I have had the opportunity to evaluate existing Docker container patterns and try to reduce pain points within the applications. One area I wish to address is the support pipeline of infrastructure within the container needing to be updated or patched. The containers tend to be application servers with a single deployable application component (e.g. Apache Tomcat running a single Jakarta servlet or Gunicorn running a Flask app). The pain comes from needing to update the application server base image, requiring each of the containers to be updated to use this parent, creating a large amount of overhead.

For example, I have a Gunicorn setup I have defined in container X and 50 Flask applications (1, 2, …, 50) with containers X<sub>1</sub>, X<sub>2</sub>, …, X<sub>50</sub> that inherit from X. I'm assuming that either (a) no application component has any external dependencies or (b) all external dependencies for an application component are included within it. If I update X to include a security patch, then I will need to rebuild X<sub>1</sub>, X<sub>2</sub>, …, X<sub>50</sub> to include this patch before they are then applied to the appropriate container management system (e.g. Kubernetes).

## Concept

The solution I have been exploring involves keeping the application server and application component in distinct parts (e.g. "X" and "1, 2, …, 50") and combining them at deployment time by mounting the component into the filesystem of X. The idea is that splitting them up will allow the two parts to serve their individual purposes rather than a single container accomplishing both.

Using the Kubernetes Deployment specification, it would look something like this:

```yaml
# An instance of "app1" running on Gunicorn. Imagine similar apps
# running such as "app2" through to "app50" with a similar deployment
# setup.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app1-1.0.0
  labels:
    app: app1
    version: "1.0.0"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app1
      version: "1.0.0"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app1
        version: "1.0.0"
    spec:
      containers:
        # Newly patched Gunicorn application sever image
        - name: gunicorn
          image: my-gunicorn-image:1.0.1
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          volumeMounts:
            - name: app
              mountPath: /home/app
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1
              memory: 2Gi
      volumes:
        # Existing instance of app1 kept in an arbitrary mount
        # location. In practice, I have been using a combination of
        # `emptyDir` and `initContainers` to prepare application
        # components.
        - name: app
          configMap:
            name: app1
```

The current advantage I can see in this method is that there is no need to build a container for each application component, saving on space in the container repository. Within the context of Kubernetes, there could also be some merit in being able to discover all deployments that use a specific application server version rather than needing to look at the Dockerfiles of the individual projects or relying on metadata.

Other qualities of this method end up being remarkably similar to just having a container per application component. For example, updates to use a new version of the application server would be migrated to the deployment phase instead of the container build and testing of application components would likely need to be done in the context of a specific application server version.

## Question

Does the concept of containerizing the application server and providing the application components as parameters (e.g. through mounting) contradict the purpose of containerizing applications? Are there any obvious flaws to this method that I am missing?

That is, am I better off having each application component as its own container to be deployed?

Comment: I would treat the base image as any other dependency to the application.